# Load another View after successful TouchID login

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, touch-id

I played around a bit with TouchID and I have the following question:

After successful TouchID login, how do I present a new ViewController?

The code in the viewController.m is:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import LocalAuthentication;
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
        NSError *error;

        // check if the policy can be evaluated
        if (![context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
            NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't evaluate policy! %@", error.localizedDescription];
            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:msg];
            return;
        }

        // evaluate
        [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                localizedReason:@"Please login through TouchID"
                          reply:
         ^(BOOL success, NSError *authenticationError) {

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                 if (success) {
                     [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Everything Worked!"];
                     //Code for new viewController should come here!
                 }
                 else {
                     NSLog(@"error:%@", authenticationError);
                     [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FAILED! %@", authenticationError.localizedDescription]];
                 }
             });
         }];
    }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

viewController.h is standart. Nothing changed in it.
Thanks for support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To present a view controller we normally use following methods

1. If we are using storyboard,then call following method

   `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"indentifierForViewController" sender:self];`

   2. If we are not using storyboard then we can use

   `NextTaskViewControler *add = [[NextTaskViewControler alloc]
                            initWithNibName:@"NextTaskViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:nextTaskVC animated:YES completion:nil];`

I suggest you to use UINavigationController, a specialized view controller that manages other view controllers to provide a hierarchical navigation for the user. Present a viewcontroller only for specific purpose such as presenting a photo with few actions in it.It's easy to maintain when view hierarchy becomes complex

Please go-through  [UINavigationController Refrence](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html)